# get the reference of cell adjacent to your Active cell VBA

Tags: excel, vba

The hardcode reference I am talking about is lets suppose C2. I already have some value stored in C2 and I want to combine this C2 value with the second value. And I want my Second value to go from the Active Cell.

Assume that my Active cell address is A7. Is there a way to combine the data of A7 and C2 together, and then paste it in the cell which is adjacent to Active Cell i.e., "A8" in my case. Watching ahead!

I have written this line of code to give the reference of cell which is active now.

```
cell2 = ActiveCell.Value
```

And the below code to access the cell next to my currently active cell. e.g., IF Cell " A7 " is active, it will refer to the cell "A8".

```
result = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1)
```

I've assigned already " C2 " to my cell1, because there is already some value stored in it.

Here is the complete code

```
Private Sub CombineTwoCells()
    Dim cell1 As String
    Dim cell2 As String 
    Dim result As String
    Dim check As Range
    Do
        cell1 = "C2"
        Set check = Intersect(Range(cell1).Cells(1, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells)
    Loop Until Not check Is Nothing
    Do
        cell2 = ActiveCell.Value
        Set result = Intersect(Range(cell2), ActiveSheet.Cells)
    Loop Until Not result Is Nothing
    Do
        result = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1)
        Set check = Intersect(Range(result), ActiveSheet.Cells)
    Loop Until Not check Is Nothing
    Range(result) = Range(cell1) & Range(cell2)
End Sub
```

Comment: `activecell.offset(,1).value=activecell.value & range("c2").value` ?

Comment: already compiled in excel default format? Do you need more explanation?

Comment: Somebody else edited your question to format it properly. Please get in the habit of doing it yourself in future, there's plenty of guidance around the site.